# How to compile a Java file with dependencies in a Windows command prompt window?

Tags: java, build, jar, dependencies

I am using a jar file that is dependent to a *GitHub* source file, available here: [Java Stream Player (Library)](https://github.com/goxr3plus/java-stream-player). The jar file is named `musicplayer-1.0.0.jar`. The jar file has the following manifest (`MANIFEST.MF`):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Class-Path: lib/slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar lib/l
 ogback-core-1.2.3.jar lib/java-stream-player-10.0.0.jar lib/mp3spi-1.9.
 5.4.jar lib/jlayer-1.0.1.4.jar lib/junit-3.8.2.jar lib/jflac-codec-1.5.
 2.jar lib/vorbis-support-1.1.0.jar lib/tritonus-all-0.3.7.2.jar lib/jor
 bis-0.0.17-2.jar lib/jaudiotagger-2.2.7.jar lib/commons-io-2.6.jar
Implementation-Title: musicplayer
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: gr.hua.dit.oop2.musicplayer.MusicPlayerApp
```

The build file is the following in *Maven*:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And the dependency is defined with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.goxr3plus</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-stream-player</artifactId>
        <version>Tag</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I compile my code in cmd with simple commands without using *Maven* (or any other tool)?

The commands I use are:

```
javac -classpath musicplayer-1.0.0.jar Jukebox.java
java Jukebox Vivaldi-Storm.mp3
```

`musicplayer-1.0.0.jar` is the jar file that uses the *GitHub* source code,
`Jukebox.java` is my java file and `Vivaldi-Storm.mp3` is an argument needed by my class.

The second command results in the error exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.goxr3plus.streamplayer.stream.StreamPlayerListener

I can't use a simple import leading to the external source code like:

```
import com.goxr3plus.streamplayer.stream.*;
```

Comment: Wait, if the **second** command fails, the first one should have completed successfully, should it not? In that case you last sentence "I can't use a simple import ..." does not make sense to me. Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: You are doing this the hard way.  Just install and use Maven.

Comment: @StephenC Well, if someone is learning Java, it might make sense to do stuff like this without tools like Gradle or Maven to understand what classpath is and how classpath works.

Comment: Well yea.  But don't do it on a complicated project with a stack of dependencies, etc.  Do it with something simple.   And note that the OP didn't tell us why he doesn't want to use Maven.

Comment: @ThomasBehr Yes the compilation is successful. The problem is a run time error, which has to do with the external library from the url. I had some problems with Maven installation. There was a problem with my Java path and after trying a lot I decided to do it in a more independent - yet complicated - way. 
I could download the library from the url and create a jar file - but I would prefer not to unzip and change the jar file I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute your `JukeBox` using the second command, you need to use the `-classpath` option, too. However, when executing `java` you need to specify `musicplayer-1.0.0.jar` **and** all its dependencies in the classpath value. E.g. you need to download the goxr3plus java-stream-player and add that to your classpath as well. Then you need to do that for all the other dependencies of musicplayer as well.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So, I must download the code from the url and use it as an external library (as jar files?). Ex: java -classpath goxr3plus-java-stream-player.jar ; musicplayer-1.0.0.jar Jukebox arguments

Comment: @JohnZacharakis Exactly.